# WebApp won't compile in CentOS 7 server, but does compile in Windows

Tags: linux, centos, permissions, eclipse, maven

I am getting a "resource marked as read-only" error when I try to compile a war file on a CentOS 7 installation.  But the same eclipse project does not throw any compilation error on Windows after I zip the project up, transfer it to windows, and then import it into eclipse in windows.  I have tried changing file permissions, but the compilation error remains.  **How can I resolve this error so that the war file can compile on my CentOS 7 server?**

The very first line of the pom.xml in an eclipse spring mvc maven project is showing the following compilation error:

```
Parent of resource: /path/to/myworkspace/MinimalDbaseExample/target/m2e-wtp is marked as read-only.
```

This error showed up after I navigated the terminal to the root folder of the directory and typed `mvn clean install`.

I have uploaded a zipped copy of the sample project to a file sharing site.  You can [download the zipped project from this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/0x6m1y4ipqmOavRT45Jg?b=tg6fSdszaTyc1Bz14WWc)  in order to reproduce the error on your machine in a minute or two.

Note: I read [this other posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19771812/cannnot-build-java-project-in-eclipse-parent-of-resource-is-marked-read-only), and then tried the following from the CentOS terminal:

```
chmod -R ugo+rw /path/to/myworkspace/MinimalDbaseExample/target/
```

And I also tried:

```
chmod -R 0777 /path/to/myworkspace/MinimalDbaseExample
```

But eclipse is still showing the compilation error, even after multiple `Project clean`  and `Maven update` operations.  I thus assumed it was not an OS problem, but then I switched to windows, downloaded the zip from the link above, imported it into eclipse in windows, and did `Run As...Run on Server`.  The project did not show the compilation error in windows.  **Is there something else I can do in CentOS 7 to fix this?**

**How can I resolve this error?**

Comment: What is `/path/to` in reality?

Comment: @michaelhampton It is the same path as all the other projects in the workspace, and the other projects all work. I am logging in through my phone now. But I can check the path when I am back at my computer in a few hours if it is important.

Comment: @MichaelHampton `/home/user/workspace/` is the real `/path/to/myworkspace/`.  Does this make a difference?